# nginx conflicting location matching with path parameters

Tags: express, nginx

In my upstream backend, i have the following routes

```
router.get("/minted, controllers.minted);
router.get("/eligible", controllers.eligible);
...more routes
router.get("/:id", controllers.uri);
```

I'm confused as to how the nginx location should be, so that only `/1`, `/2` etc get matched to `/:id` and the others at their respective routes.

I have the following config, but I am not sure nginx could determine that `/minted` should not be matched with `/:id`?

```
location /:id {
    proxy_pass http://backend/:id;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```